# Represent the data from a string observable in JSON

Tags: angular, observable

I have an observable which contains string data and i need to retrieve this string and use it in a JSON, but i am not sure how to subscribe to the observable within the json object. I am quite new to observables so there could be something simple i am missing. Please see the below code to explain this better (href in the json is a string):

```js
public settingsSideNav: Observable<ISideNavItem[]>;

public ngOnInit(): void {
  this.settingsSideNav = this.testURL(this.betaUser());
}


public testURL(urmURL : any): Observable<ISideNavItem[]> {
  return urmURL
   .pipe(
         first(),
          map(
              url => {
                      return [{ name: 'Manage Users', href: url}];
                    },
                )
            );
}





public betaUser(): Observable<string> {
  return this.capabilityService.getCapabilities()
      .pipe(
          map(
             capabilities => {
                        let manageUsersURL : string;
                        if (user = "test") {
                            url = "test";
                        } else {
                            url = "user";
                        }
                        return manageUsersURL;
                    }
                )
            );
    }
}
```

```html
<span [sideNavConfig]="settingsSideNav | async"></span>
```

Comment: You have to subscribe the observable (testURL). and within subscription success method create your json (sideNavItems). Inside subscription success method you will get the results (capabilities) as a parameter.

Comment: thanks @DaniyalAwan, i have updated the code but i still seem to have an issue where the data from the observable is not loading on the screen, i updated the code above